Error when compiling spring project to integrate saml2
good day, I am encountering this error that occurs when compiling my project.
I was looking into this error but couldn't find a possible solution.
These are the dependencies I am using and the part of the security code that I implemented
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.thymeleaf.extras</groupId>
            <artifactId>thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity6</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-saml2-service-provider</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.opensaml</groupId>
            <artifactId>opensaml-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.opensaml</groupId>
            <artifactId>opensaml-saml-api</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.opensaml</groupId>
            <artifactId>opensaml-saml-impl</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <skipTests>true</skipTests>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>shibboleth_repository</id>
            <name>Shibboleth Maven Repository</name>
            <url>https://build.shibboleth.net/nexus/content/repositories/releases/</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>shibboleth_repository_2</id>
            <name>Shibboleth Maven Repository (https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.opensaml/opensaml-core/4.3.2)</name>
            <url>https://build.shibboleth.net/maven/releases/</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>shibboleth_repository</id>
            <name>Shibboleth Maven Repository</name>
            <url>https://build.shibboleth.net/nexus/content/repositories/releases/</url>
        </pluginRepository>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>shibboleth_repository_2</id>
            <name>Shibboleth Maven Repository (https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.opensaml/opensaml-core/4.3.2)</name>
            <url>https://build.shibboleth.net/maven/releases/</url>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>

</project>

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {
    @Autowired
    RelyingPartyRegistrationRepository relyingPartyRegistrationRepository;

    // change : Return a Spring Bean SecurityFilterChain
    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());
        // Create a filter to handle generation of SAML Metadata file
        Saml2MetadataFilter filter = new Saml2MetadataFilter(
                (RelyingPartyRegistrationResolver)new DefaultRelyingPartyRegistrationResolver(this.relyingPartyRegistrationRepository),
                new OpenSamlMetadataResolver());

        // Actual code to extract the Authorities (or roles) from the Assertion
        Converter<Assertion, Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority>> authoritiesExtractor =  assertion -> {

            List<SimpleGrantedAuthority> userRoles
                    = assertion.getAttributeStatements().stream()
                    .map(AttributeStatement::getAttributes)
                    .flatMap(Collection::stream)
                    .filter(attr -> "groups".equalsIgnoreCase(attr.getName()))
                    .map(Attribute::getAttributeValues)
                    .flatMap(Collection::stream)
                    .map(xml -> new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_" + xml.getDOM().getTextContent()))
                    .toList();
            return userRoles;
        };

        // change : Create a version of SAML Authenticator Provider which will convert the
        // "groups" claim into Authorities in the SAML 2 Authentication object
        Converter<ResponseToken, Saml2Authentication> authConvertor
                = OpenSaml4AuthenticationProvider.createDefaultResponseAuthenticationConverter();
        OpenSaml4AuthenticationProvider samlAuthProv = new OpenSaml4AuthenticationProvider();
        samlAuthProv.setResponseAuthenticationConverter((responseToken) -> {

            // Make sure the authorities are set in the SAML Authentication
            Saml2Authentication authentication = authConvertor.convert(responseToken);
            Assertion assertion = responseToken.getResponse().getAssertions().get(0);
            AuthenticatedPrincipal principal = (AuthenticatedPrincipal) authentication.getPrincipal();
            Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> authorities = authoritiesExtractor.convert(assertion);
            return new Saml2Authentication(principal, authentication.getSaml2Response(), authorities);
        });


        http
                .saml2Login(withDefaults())
                .saml2Logout(withDefaults())
                .authenticationProvider(samlAuthProv) // change : register the new SAML Auth provider
                .addFilterBefore(filter, Saml2WebSsoAuthenticationFilter.class)
                .authorizeHttpRequests(authorize ->
                        authorize
                                .requestMatchers("/", "/carsonline", "/buy/**", "/user").hasAnyRole("cars.user","cars.admin")
                                .requestMatchers("/edit/**").hasAnyRole("cars.admin")
                                .anyRequest().authenticated());

        // change : return the SecurityFilterChain
        return http.build();
    }

Error that appears in my log
2024-06-21T12:46:51.027-06:00 DEBUG 24712 --- [  restartedMain] o.o.xmlsec.algorithm.AlgorithmRegistry   : AlgorithmDescriptor failed runtime support check: http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#ripemd160

java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: RIPEMD160 MessageDigest not available
        at java.base/sun.security.jca.GetInstance.getInstance(GetInstance.java:159) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.security.MessageDigest.getInstance(MessageDigest.java:185) ~[na:na]
        at org.opensaml.xmlsec.algorithm.AlgorithmRegistry.checkRuntimeSupports(AlgorithmRegistry.java:326) ~[opensaml-xmlsec-api-4.3.2.jar:na]
        at org.opensaml.xmlsec.algorithm.AlgorithmRegistry.index(AlgorithmRegistry.java:253) ~[opensaml-xmlsec-api-4.3.2.jar:na]
        at org.opensaml.xmlsec.algorithm.AlgorithmRegistry.register(AlgorithmRegistry.java:149) ~[opensaml-xmlsec-api-4.3.2.jar:na]
        at org.opensaml.xmlsec.config.GlobalAlgorithmRegistryInitializer.init(GlobalAlgorithmRegistryInitializer.java:49) ~[opensaml-xmlsec-api-4.3.2.jar:na]
        at org.opensaml.core.config.InitializationService.initialize(InitializationService.java:57) ~[opensaml-core-4.3.2.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.security.saml2.core.OpenSamlInitializationService.initialize(OpenSamlInitializationService.java:122) ~[spring-security-saml2-service-provider-6.3.0.jar:6.3.0]
        at org.springframework.security.saml2.core.OpenSamlInitializationService.initialize(OpenSamlInitializationService.java:97) ~[spring-security-saml2-service-provider-6.3.0.jar:6.3.0]
        at org.springframework.security.saml2.provider.service.registration.OpenSamlMetadataRelyingPartyRegistrationConverter.<clinit>(OpenSamlMetadataRelyingPartyRegistrationConverter.java:53) ~[spring-security-saml2-service-provider-6.3.0.jar:6.3.0]

I tried placing this dependency and this part in my main method
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
            <artifactId>bcprov-jdk15on</artifactId>
            <version>1.64</version>
        </dependency>

Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());

But I still get the same error mentioned above.
Thanks for your support.
